# How many missings are too many to impute data with the AMELIA II package?

Tags: r, panel-data, missing-data, prior, multiple-imputation

I have a very large longitudinal dataset. I only want to impute 3 variables individually using the AMELIA package in R. The problem is that some individuals have a lot of missing values, so I want to include the individuals that have enough answers for AMELIA to properly work. What is the minimum response threshold required for AMELIA to properly work? 50%, 60%, 70%? Does adding a ridge prior help?

Comment: This is likely to depend on the correlational structure in your data, and may not have a general answer.  I'd start with complete cases and artificially create missing data in the various proportions and see how the error increases with the % missing (assuming your original data is missing at random).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236362/is-there-an-upper-limit-in-the-proportion-of-missing-data-to-be-imputed?rq=1